# Ubuntu Server 14.04 cant find RAID

Tags: 14.04, server, raid

I trying to install Ubuntu Server on old Server with Intel S5000VSA motherboard with created RAID0 on SAS, but installator can't find an driver for discs. I found only [a this driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13814/SAS-Storage-Driver-for-Linux-?product=77877) but it support only RedHat and Suse linux.

Is it possible to install on this machine Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Try it and see.  This driver is likely part of the linux kernel for several years now and should just work.  I would suggest using 16.04 though rather than 14.04.

Comment: Pure Ubuntu Server ISO can't find RAID, so I'will try to use this driver.

Comment: Does it see the individual drives?  If so, then this may be a fake raid controller, in which case you are better off just configuring linux software raid.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it doesn't see any HDD - SAS driver on USB not detected by installer too.